# Can I waterproof a tent just before it rains?

Tags: tents, waterproofing

I am camping this weekend and my new tent just arrived today. I want to put it up and waterproof it now with a spray-on silicone waterproofer and a seam sealer.

It's evening right now and very bright/sunny/hot but we're expecting a short storm late this night.  If I waterproof the tent now, will the rain nullify the waterproofing?

Comment: Why do you want to spray your new tent? It should be good already. If you need to apply seam sealer it's best to do that when it's had a chance to stretch, then leave it up while the sealer dries (or at least that was true last time I did it).

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0001FYL2M/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01KU8I8MI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @Residualfail those won't work for the OP. The first says "cures in 72 hours", and the second needs to dry overnight.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum I am the OP haha.  I misread what ChrisH was asking.  Thought he wanted to know what I was spraying with so I linked my products.  That's what I get for posting without coffee....

Comment: @Residualfail I'll take that same excuse for not noticing you're the OP 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most products require 24-48 hours of dry time.  Some also recommend multiple coats, with some time (i.e. 4 hours) between coats.

> Allow article to dry for 24-48 hours [Source](http://us.kiwicare.com/products/kiwi-camp-dry-heavy-duty-water-repellent)

We often spray waterproofing on our fabrics in the garage.  This keeps them out of the rain while drying and allows for ventilation, while drying.

Comment: Good idea about spraying it down in the garage

Answer (score 4):

If one were to discover a leaking section of fabric *during* a rainstorm, a highly effective solution is to rub wax (candle, ski wax, paraffin, etc.) on the fabric.  No need to heat it:  rubbing cold works fine.  It is better to apply from the outside, but it works okay from the (more comfortable and convenient) inside too.  One rubbing generally lasts for several days.